# Why does honey stored with the comb last longer?

Tags: storage-method, honey

I recently discovered that honey stored in containers with the comb does not seem to crystallize (or certainly not as fast as when stored without).  What is the mechanism that causes this? Is there a real downside to storing with the comb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bees add enzymes to honey that prevent crystallization. These enzymes are destroyed by many of the processing techniques, like heating, but such techniques also physically destroy the comb, so they're not used on the honey that is in the comb.

This type of honey is also called `raw honey` sometimes.

As a side note, crystallized honey is fine for consumption. If you want to get rid of the crystals you can easily do so by heating the jar a bit.

Comment: So honey that is separated (only) by centrifuge should last longer than others?

Comment: Well, not exactly, raw honey will not crystallize as quickly, but the heating is also done to sterilize it. Crystallized honey is still fine for consumption for a long time. Maybe the raw honey will go bad in another way earlier, but I'm sure it will take ages.
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/54872/jewish/Fifty-Year-Old-Honey.htm

Answer (score 3):

Honey, technically, never spoils. They have [found](http://www.foresthoney.com/index.php?acao=glossary&glossary_id=14) it in the Egyptian tombs and it's still "good."

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but if you warm the crystalised honey a little it will liquify again and will remain liquid for a period of time afterwards - nearly as long as it took to crystalise the first time.

Comment: Also mentioned here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1122/can-i-prevent-honey-from-congealing-hardening-in-the-pantry